# Flask url_for not using https behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: python, nginx, flask, reverse-proxy, cherrypy

I have a Flask app running on CherryPy locally as `http://localhost:5000` which is then exposed through an Nginx reverse proxy as `https://some.website.com`

The issue I'm having is that each time my app calls `redirect(url_for('some.endpoint'))` it returns a `http://` redirect.

Normally I would correct this issue with a url rewrite rule, but that is not possible in my scenario because all http port 80 traffic is being blocked at the firewall level and only https traffic is accepted by the server.

I've been able to cheat my way around this for now by adding the `_external=True, _scheme='https'` parameters on the `url_for` function but I'm running into issues all over the place like in the `@login_required` decorator breaking because it tries to redirect the user to `http://some.website.com/login` which just times out after the connection is rejected.

Within the Flask config object I have set:

```
PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME = "https"
```

but this has no effect on the issue.

I have also added the following headers to the nginx.conf file:

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For          $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto        https;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl          on;
proxy_set_header   X-Url-Scheme             https;
```

which also has no effect.

Has anyone with a similar issue found a solution to this?

---

**EDIT:** I have included the ProxyFix middleware from `werkzeig.contrib.fixers` by adding the line `flask_app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(flask_app.wsgi_app)` to my app before `cherrypy.engine.start()` is called, I'm still having the same issue even after restarting the server and clearing all cache:

[image: screenshot]

Could it be possible that CherryPy needs any additional config options?